# what is the max number of requests Nginx server allow client to send in one HTTP 1.1 connection

Tags: http, nginx

HTTP  client could send multiple requests in one HTTP 1.1  connection due to Keep alive feature.

But is there any limit of that number in protocol?

If not, what is the implementation for Nginx about that? Does it have any configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [100](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_requests) for nginx 1.9.9 or earlier and 1000, for nginx 1.9.10 and later.

The`keepalive_requests` directive (default is 100/1000) allows you to configure the maximum number of requests done through a single keepalive connection. From documentation link above:

> Sets the maximum number of requests that can be served through one keep-alive connection. After the maximum number of requests are made, the connection is closed.

A mere equivalent for this directive in HTTP/2 is [http2_max_requests](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_requests)

Comment: That's it, thank you. And does HTTP 1.1 protocol set any limit about it ?

Comment: I don't think so. At least there's no rationale that I see, for having such a limit (as long as both server and client are happy to exchange stuff over single connection forever, why not let them :)

Comment: Since nginx 1.19.10, it's [1000](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_requests).